# Objective-C and autorelease on return

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

Are the two methods

```
- (id) myFirstMethod
{
  NSObject* anObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  [anObject autorelease];
  return anObject;
}

- (id) mySecondMethod
{
  NSObject* anObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  return [anObject autorelease];
}
```

identical?

Comment: Neither method is actually valid — the brackets around the object are not correct.

Comment: @Chuck - right, they're just typos. Edited out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the both methods are identical. Whenever you write a nested function or same code in multiple lines, it is all the same after compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do everything in the return:

```
- (id) myThirdMethod {
    return [[[NSObject alloc]init]autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I could - but too ugly for my eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are identical, but all they do is to cause a compiler error.

`[anObject]` is not allowed. And `NSObject anObject` is also invalid syntax.